# How to get openssl to use a cert without specifying it via -CAfile

Tags: certificates, openssl, ubuntu

I'm using this command:

```
openssl s_client -connect example.com:443 -CAfile /etc/ssl/certs/GTE_CyberTrust_Global_Root.pem
```

It works. If I don't specify that CAfile I get a code 20. The cert is in `/etc/ssl/certs` and `/usr/lib/ssl/certs -> /etc/ssl/certs` It's also included in the `ca-certificates.crt`

What's governing whether openssl can find my cert or not and how can I get it to accept this cert without explicitly specifying it?

Comment: Is `GTE_CyberTrust_Global_Root.pem` an intermediate CA? If so, it may be that your webserver is failing to serve that intermediate CA cert along with your site cert. This shortcoming on the part of your webserver could cause compatibility issues with some computers. On the other hand, if the `GTE_CyberTrust_Global_Root.pem` is a top-level root certificate then it should be working by default.

Comment: @GeorgeBailey Thanks. It is intermediate. No real reason not to share the location: bigfishgames-a.akamaihd.net:443 If I'm asking our web folks to fix this, what would I be asking? Feel free to make your answer an answer (i.e. "Nothing you can do on the client, the server needs to do X").

Comment: That's strange. I would have expected it to work once included in /etc/ssl/certs and ca-certificates.crt

Comment: Well it's not obvious yet whether the server is the problem. It looks like the server is serving **an** Intermediate CA, and that SSLLabs treats CyberTrust as a top-level root. You may be wrong about CyberTrust being an Intermediate, but maybe you are right. I'm not sure. Check the certificate chain/path in your favorite browser and/or [on SSLLabs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=bigfishgames-a.akamaihd.net). Perhaps `openssl` is not configured with any top-level root certs? Have you tried `google.com:443`?

Comment: Same behavior for google.com

Comment: Effectively dupe http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/117651/why-doesnt-openssl-s-client-correctly-validate-google-com443 for detail see http://superuser.com/questions/903247/ssl-root-ca-certificate-is-not-recognized-although-present-in-the-trust-store/

Comment: It's possible you have to rehash the /certs directory: `openssl rehash /etc/ssl/certs`. "...many programs that use OpenSSL require directories to be set up like this in order to find certificates." https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man1/rehash.html. You can't necessarily just drop the cert in the dir without rehashing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a known OpenSSL bug where s_client doesn't check the default certificate store when you don't pass the `-CApath` or `-CAfile` argument.  OpenSSL on Ubuntu 14.04 suffers from this bug as I'll demonstrate:

Version:

```
ubuntu@puppetmaster:/etc/ssl$ openssl version
OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
```

Fails to use the default store when I don't pass the `-ca:

```
ubuntu@puppetmaster:/etc/ssl$ openssl s_client -quiet -connect gmail.com:443
depth=2 C = US, O = GeoTrust Inc., CN = GeoTrust Global CA
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
verify return:0
```

Now I pass null as the `-CApath` and it works:

```
ubuntu@puppetmaster:/etc/ssl$ openssl s_client -quiet -connect gmail.com:443 -CApath /dev/null
depth=3 C = US, O = Equifax, OU = Equifax Secure Certificate Authority
verify return:1
depth=2 C = US, O = GeoTrust Inc., CN = GeoTrust Global CA
verify return:1
depth=1 C = US, O = Google Inc, CN = Google Internet Authority G2
verify return:1
depth=0 C = US, ST = California, L = Mountain View, O = Google Inc, CN = mail.google.com
verify return:1
```

Unfortunately I don't think a list of affected OpenSSL versions exists.  Only way to know is to test it.

Comment: Thanks. I was using that version. OpenSSL 1.1.0 does not appear to have fixed the issue. I'm not seeing the issue listed here: https://github.com/openssl/openssl/issues Can you reference the issue?

Comment: It's in the [old RT issue tracker](https://rt.openssl.org).  There is a patch there, it's behind a login (guest:guest)  It's issue #3697, marked resolved.

https://rt.openssl.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=3697

Comment: Ok, I confirmed that this is fixed in 1.1, at least in the richsalz fork of it. When I upgraded I initially did not notice the base directory shifted to `/usr/local/ssl` which had a certs directory not mapped to `/etc/ssl/certs`.

Comment: I can verify the bug exists in CentOS 6.8  (OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013).

Comment: Also `openssl version -d` gives you the base config directory ...

Comment: It's fixed on the real 1.1 development branch as well. https://github.com/openssl/openssl

Answer (score 2):

```
"How to get openssl to use a cert without specifying it via -CAfile".
```

I had the same requirement.  I wanted to use a directory of CAs that I "trusted" locally.  I did not want any default `Trust store` polluting results.

**c_rehash**

Before calling the `verify` command, the help page: `man verify` guided me to use `c_rehash`:

> rehash scans directories and calculates a hash value of each ".pem", ".crt", ".cer", or ".crl" file in the specified directory list and creates symbolic links
> for each file

```
export CERTS=/Users/{path_to_your_certs}
[path to openssl]/openssl/bin/c_rehash ${CERTS}
```

**Verify a leaf cert**

```
openssl verify -CApath ${CERTS} local_leaf.pem
local_leaf.pem: OK
```

You load the Root CA and IntCA inside of directory `CERTS`.   If I didn't do the rehash step it would give me error 20 `unable to get local issuer certificate`.

Comment: You can also use `openssl rehash $dir_keystore` for this.