# Use openssl to individually verify components of a certificate chain

Tags: certificates, openssl, x.509

This is related to another question, [How to verify a signature of one entity by another using OpenSSL CLI?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/117515/)

I used `openssl s_client -showcerts -connect www.google.com:443` to collect three certificates from google.  Call them `g0`, `g1`, `g2`, where:

- `g0` is a leaf cert signed by Google's intermediate CA
- `g1` holds the intermediate CA public key and is signed by GeoTrust CA
- `g2` holds the GeoTrust public key and is signed by EquiFax CA

My goal is to demonstrate that this is a valid signature chain, step-by-step, using the OpenSSL CLI.  The intuitive try is this:

```
$ openssl verify -CAfile g1 g0
```

But it turns out that OpenSSL is using certs from its trusted store (see [How to verify a signature of one entity by another using OpenSSL CLI?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/117515/)).  So instead I kill the trusted store as @dave_thompson_085 suggested in a comment to the above-referenced question.  But this doesn't seem to work:

```
$ openssl verify -CApath /dev/null -CAfile g1 g0
g1.crt: C = US, O = Google Inc, CN = Google Internet Authority G2
error 2 at 1 depth lookup:unable to get issuer certificate
```

So how do I correctly issue this `verify` command in such a way that I can specifically check whether `g1` has signed `g0`?

```
$ openssl version
OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've more-or-less solved my problem as follows:

There is an option to `verify` called `-partial_chain` that allows verify to output `OK` without finding a chain that lands at self-signed trusted root cert. However, `-partial_chain` doesn't exist on the version of OpenSSL that I have, nor in any later version of 1.0.1.  Here's the run-down:

- OpenSSL 1.0.1f -- This is the latest for Ubuntu 14.04; it has the heartbleed fix
- OpenSSL 1.0.1s -- This is the latest in the 1.0.1 line, and likely to be the last; must be installed by hand in Ubuntu 14.04
- OpenSSL 1.0.2g -- Currently the latest in the 1.0.2 line; this does support `-partial_chain`
- OpenSSL 1.1 -- This is currently in alpha and has even more options, but I didn't explore it

So, with `1.0.2g` or later, one can do the following:

```
$ openssl verify -CApath /dev/null -partial_chain -trusted g1 g0
g0: OK
$ openssl verify -CApath /dev/null -partial_chain -trusted g2 g1
g1: OK
$ openssl verify -CApath /dev/null -trusted /etc/ssl/certs/EquiFax_Secure_CA.pem g2
g2: OK
```

(Note that `-partial_chain` was not needed in the last command since the Equifax root cert is self-signed.)

This satisfies my question, but requires a version of OpenSSL that is not yet available on some distros unless you hand-install.  If you are stuck with a pre-1.0.2 version, you probably have to use @Anthony Geoghegan's method.

**Note:** There is an option listed in the `verify` docs called `-no-CApath` which purportedly obviates the need for `-CApath /dev/null`, but it's not available on 1.0.2g or earlier, based on my tests.  I assume it is available in 1.1.

Comment: That's some great research. I hadn't heard of the `-partial_chain` option  (it's not available on any of my own systems).

Answer (score 8):

The OpenSSL `verify` command builds up a complete certificate chain (until it reaches a self-signed CA certificate) in order to verify a certificate. From its man page:

> Firstly a certificate chain is built up starting from the supplied
>   certificate and ending in the root CA. It is an error if the whole chain
>   cannot be built up.

It only returns a positive result if it can verify the **complete chain**.

> If any operation fails then the certificate is not valid.

However, the following command results provide enough information to show that the *g0* certificate **is signed** by the *g1* certificate.

```
$ openssl verify -CApath /dev/null -CAfile g1 g0
g1.crt: C = US, O = Google Inc, CN = Google Internet Authority G2
error 2 at 1 depth lookup:unable to get issuer certificate
```

**Error 2** indicates that one of the certificates in the chain could not be
found.

> 2 X509_V_ERR_UNABLE_TO_GET_ISSUER_CERT: unable to get issuer certificate
>
> the issuer certificate of a looked up certificate could not be found. This
>   normally means the list of trusted certificates is not complete.

The important thing here is that the *depth* is 1. This indicates that the certificate being checked was verified at the first level, *depth 0* (by the *g1* certificate).

If the *g1* certificate was **not** used to sign the *g0* certificate, the error would be at the first stage, *depth 0* and you would instead receive **Error 20**:

```
error 20 at 0 depth lookup:unable to get local issuer certificate
```

> 20 X509_V_ERR_UNABLE_TO_GET_ISSUER_CERT_LOCALLY: unable to get local issuer
>   certificate
>
> the issuer certificate could not be found: this occurs if the issuer
>   certificate of an untrusted certificate cannot be found.

Comment: My question was how to verify `g1` signed `g0`.  Involving `g2` doesn't make sense to me here, nor does involving EquiFax's root cert from the trusted store.  Can I not just verify this one sig without having to invoke the rest of the chain to some self-signed root?  Or is this not supported by OpenSSL?

Comment: Sorry @Fixee  I misinterpreted your question (it was late at night for me and I only glanced at the related question). I've now changed my answer based on your clarification.

Answer (score 0):

To verify that issuer of `cert1.crt` is `cert1Issuer.crt`:

```
openssl verify -no-CAfile -no-CApath -partial_chain -trusted cert1Issuer.crt cert1.crt
# cert1.crt : OK
```