# How to reliably identify a certificate as root certificate in a chain

Tags: certificates, certificate-authority, validation

Assume you have a certificate (X509 v3) chain sent to you for validation. The chain sent to you may or may not include the root CA certificate. Is there a reliable way to find out whether this is the case?

Quite obviously only the certificate at the top of the hierarchy may be the root CA certificate, but how would I check this? I came up with a check for equality between issuer and subject, and this seems to work fine for all cases I found so far, but I'm not sure whether is foolproof.

**Edit:** This is not about a manual check or about which tool to use, it's about a programmatic check. So using openSSl to perform checks (as suggested in a 'possible duplicate' claim) is not an option. The question is which certificate attributes or extensions I can use in which fashion to reliably identify a root CA certificate in a given chain.

To make the question even more to the point: I suggested to check whether `subject==issuer` right from the beginning. The question is whether this is a foolproof approach. So is it possible to rely on the fact that this is true if and only if it is a root certificate? What happens if I create a root certificate and a derived intermediate CA certificate and, in the latter, just choose the subject equal to the issuer? Will that result in a valid certificate? (The authority key identifier may well correctly point to the key identifier of the root CA).

(Note that I did *not* ask how to check whether I should trust the chain. I want to know how to reliably identify a root CA certificate in a chain).

Comment: "but how would I check this?" -  [Use openssl to individually verify components of a certificate chain](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/118062/use-openssl-to-individually-verify-components-of-a-certificate-chain). And the root cert is the one which is part of the chain but self-signed.

Answer (score 3):

Simply check if `Issuer` and `Subject` fields for equality. If they are equal, the certificate is self-signed and represents root certificate. Otherwise, the certificate is intermediate certificate. Of course, public key in the root certificate must validate its own signature.

Edit to follow up OP edit:

> The question is which certificate attributes or extensions I can use in which fashion to reliably identify a root CA certificate in a given chain.

you must check that `isCA` attribute of `Basic Constraints` certificate extension is set to `True` in all CA certificates. And this extension SHALL be marked critical.

> What happens if I create a root certificate and a derived intermediate CA certificate and, in the latter, just choose the subject equal to the issuer?

there are two outcomes:

> The authority key identifier may well correctly point to the key identifier of the root CA

you will create a loop in the chain which is detected by most certificate chaining engines. Otherwise, the certificate will not be a part of your chain with root and intermediate certificate.

Comment: thank you for your answer. It indicates that the check I already suggested may work, but I sitll have some doubts. See the edit to my question. Are you saying that Issuer = Subject _and_ validiation of signature will suffice?

Comment: Subject and issuer are same in the case of a Self signed certificate also. So I don't think this is a good way of determining if a certificate is CA certificate

Comment: Root CA certificates are self-signed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check two conditions:

1. Issuer is the same as the Subject
2. The certificate is trusted

The second condition is required because you might very well pass off certificates created by a random CA.